# Pandas datareader future dividends

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am able to get historical dividends fine. How do I get future dividend dates? Code below only prints up to the last dividend, not future dividends, even though the end date is in the future.

```
from pandas_datareader import data

import datetime


start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 27)

df_histdivs = data.DataReader('PG', 'yahoo-dividends', start, end)
```

**EDIT**: Can I at least get the ex-dividend data?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because it is corporate actions that can occur on an arbitrary day. This is out of the scope of `pandas-datareader` or Yahoo Finance API.

Typically it happens once a quarter. My best guess is that you can project them on the same dates in the next year and adjust for weekends/holidays.

Comment: too bad :-( I was actually hoping for record date, ex-date, payout date, etc.